# VB.net how to get public shared member contents updated from external form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, class, autocad

I have a Class in which I have subs that each have there own use inside Autocad. for one of these subs I need the user to input some data from data set I export from autocad to a WinForm.

So far I have succeeded in getting the data from autocad to a combobox in my WIndowsform. Now I need to get the selected value in the combobox back to the Public Shared variable I made in the class where the subs are in.

With my current code the message that gets written in my command line is "acad.ctb" regardless of what I select in the combobox.

'My class in which the sub are located and part of the sub

```
Public Shared CTBName As String = "acad.ctb"

<CommandMethod("REPublish")>
Public Sub PublishAllLayouts()

    'add the data set to the Combobox in the windows form
    For Each item In AcCtb
        PlotSettingSelect.CmbAcCTB.Items.Add(item)
    Next

    PlotSettingSelect.Show()

    'CTBName = PlotSettingSelect.CmbAcCTB.
    acEd.WriteMessage(CTBName)

End Sub
```

'my class in which the WinForm is located

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Class1.CTBName = CmbAcCTB.Text

    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

What do I need: After the pressing the button in the Windowsform the value selected by the user in the combobox needs to be saved in: "Public Shared CTBName as string"

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in the debugger to see what happens?  As a debugging aid, you could also convert your shared field into a shared setter function and put a breakpoint in the setter sub to see where it changes.

Comment: It doesn't actually crash It just fails to get the value from the Combobox back to the Public shared variable.

Comment: I didn't think it did crash.  Stepping through your code is still an invaluable tool in figuring out how the actual behavior of your code differs from the your mental model of how it should behave.  Maybe, for some reason, you're simply not hitting the code in `Button1_Click`; a breakpoint there which doesn't trigger would show you that.  Maybe `CmbAcCTB.Text` isn't what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure i understood the question correctly, but it seems to me as if you are calling ' acEd.WriteMessage(CTBName)' immediatly after showing the form, before the user ever had time to change the value in the combobox you created.

You could use 'ShowDialog' instead of 'Show' to block execution until the user responds, or move 'acEd.WriteMessage(CTBName)' to the eventhandler of the buttonclick, depending on which behaviour you want.

Comment: you understood perfectly :D. The 'ShowDialog' fixed my problem. The AcEd.Writemessage(CTBName) was just a check I was using to see if the value in the code was right since I need to use the value on a command later on in the code.

Comment: Glad to help, as some extra info: note that showdialog is a function that returns a 'DialogResult' Enum. If you set the DialogResult Property of your buttons on the form you created, ShowDialog will return the value of the button that was pressed on the form. You can use this for example to see if the user clicked Ok or Cancel, and take appropriate action based on the result.